# Getting cors error in express and react app while redirecting when I use passport-local strategy and not when I use passport-google-oauth20

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cors, passport.js

This is my back-end code.

```
import { config } from "dotenv"
import express,{Request,Response} from "express"
import mongoose, {ConnectOptions, Error} from "mongoose";
import DeckModal from './models/deck';
import cors from "cors"
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import User from "./models/user";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs"
import { UserDetails } from "./types/UserDetails";
import passportLocal from "passport-local"

const LocalStrategy=passportLocal.Strategy
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const GoogleStrategy =require("passport-google-oauth20")
config()

let PORT:number=5000

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

const  store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: process.env.MONGO_URI!,
  collection: 'mysessions'
});

store.on('error', function(error:Error) {
  console.log(error);
});

app.use(cors({ origin:"http://localhost:5173" ,credentials:true}))

app.set('trust proxy', 1) 

// create session
app.use(session({
  secret:process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
  resave:true,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  store:store,
  // cookie:{
  //   httpOnly:true, //An HttpOnly Cookie is a tag added to a browser cookie that prevents client-side scripts from accessing data
  //   sameSite:"none", // If your frontend and backend is hosted on different origin then use sameSite:none in order to share cookie.
  //   secure:true,      // it allows only https requests
  //   maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  // }
 
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// local strategy 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(  
  {usernameField:"email"},
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err:Error, user:UserDetails) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }  // If there is error we will return an error to done function.
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); } // If we don't find any user then we will return null and as there is no error we will send false
      bcrypt.compare(password,user.password!,(err,result)=>{
        if(err) throw err 
        if(result===true){
          return done(null,user) 
        }
        else{
          return done(null,false) 
        }
      })
    });
  }
));

//gooogle strategy 

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    async (accessToken:any, refreshToken:any, profile:any, done:any) => {
      const userInfo:UserDetails={
        email:profile.emails[0].value,
        profile_picture:profile.photos[0].value,
        username:profile.displayName
      }

      try{
        const user= await User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value })
        if(!user){
           const newUser= new User(userInfo)
           await newUser.save()
    return done(null,newUser)
       }
      return  done(null,user)
      }
      catch(err){
         return  done(null,false,err)
      }
        
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user:any,done)=>{
  return done(null,user._id)
 })

 passport.deserializeUser((id:string,done)=>{

   User.findById(id,(err:Error,doc:any)=>{
    const userInfo={
      username:doc.username, 
  email:doc.email,
  profile_picture:doc.profile_picture,
    }
     return done(null,userInfo)
 
   })
 })

// This is the recomended way to connect to the mongodb database using mongoose. source: https://docs.cyclic.sh/how-to/using-mongo-db#connection-example-mongoclient

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!,{
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
} as ConnectOptions )
.then(()=>{console.log("Connected to mongodb successfully");
// We will start to listen for request once the DB is connected
app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT,()=>{
  console.log("server is running on port "+PORT)
})
})
.catch((err:Error)=>{console.log(err)});


//Google auth
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile','email']
  // scope:['openid','profile', 'email'] 
}));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: "http://localhost:5173/login", failureMessage: true,successRedirect:"http://localhost:5173/auth/success"}));

 app.get("/getuser",(req,res)=>{
  if(req.user){

    res.json(req.user) // here we get user in req.user because passports deserialize function attaches it automatically
  }
  else{
    res.json(null)
  }
 })

 app.post('/auth/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.send('done');
  });
});



// Local auth
app.post("/signup",async(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
 const {username,email,password}=req?.body
 if(!username && !password && !email){
  res.send("Please provide name, email and password")
  return
 }
 try{
  const user:UserDetails | null=await User.findOne({username})
  if(!user){
   const hashedPassword=await bcrypt.hash(password,10) 
   const newUser= new User({
     username,
     email,
     password:hashedPassword
   })
   await newUser.save()
   res.send("success")
  
  }
  else{
   res.send("User already exist")
  }
 }
 catch(error){
  console.log(error)
 }


})



  app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
res.redirect("http://localhost:5173/auth/success")
    }
    else{
      res.status(200).json({success:false});

    }
  }
);
```

I tried redirecting using successRedirect but that is also giving me same error

```
app.post('/login', 
passport.authenticate('local',{successRedirect:"http://localhost:5173/auth/success"}));
```

**
When I authenticate using google auth it successfully redirects me but when I use local startegy for authentication it gives me cors error.**

Error message:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5173/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

The front-tend request looks like this-

for local strategy:

```
const handleLogin = async (e:FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
    const data = {  email, password };
     
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login",data,{withCredentials:true})

}
```

for google strategy:

```
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    window.open("http://localhost:5000/auth/google","_self")
  }
```